# How to get rows that fully cover a given time range?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, datetime, sql-server-2012

I'm building a web application that has a javascript chart in it. The idea is to select a time range, get the relevant data (temperatures) from the DB, deliver it to the page and display it in the chart.

The data's datetime does not come in regular intervals, so from one row to the next, the time difference can be a second as well as some minutes.

I can easily do all of that, but I ran into an issue: currently, when I want to get data for, let's say, 08:00 to 10:00, I can do this by selecting rows where the datetime field is >= 08:00 and datetime field <= 10:00, pseudo-speaking. That is ok, but that gives me gaps on the beginning and end for almost every query, because the last resp. first value most probably is not equal to the boundary.

I need the data within the given time range as well as one value *before* the range and one value *after* the range, so that I can show a continuous line from the range's start to end.

I could, of course, simply do three queries: 1. get data within the range limits, 2. get first value before the range, 3. get first value after the range. This works, but I wonder if there is a better/more elegant/more performant way of doing it? Is there maybe some fancy SQL function that I haven't heard of? I'm using Entity Framework 6 as ORM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subqueries can provide the boundary values for your reporting window, making it possible to obtain all the rows you want in a single `SELECT`:

```
SELECT captureTime, temperature FROM temperatures
WHERE captureTime >= ( 
    SELECT MAX( captureTime ) FROM temperatures
    WHERE captureTime <= '2015-01-01 08:00:00'
) AND captureTime <= (
    SELECT MIN( captureTime ) FROM temperatures 
    WHERE captureTime >= '2015-01-01 10:00:00'
)
ORDER BY captureTime
```